# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException when navigate and pass parameter

Tags: c#, maui

I have a Main page and I would pass parameters on the Page1 I get the parameter from there I would go Page2 on Page2 I would modify the object and go back to Page1 but I receive
exception.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
```

On MainPageViewModel

```
async void GoPage1()
{
   var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Test", testValue} })
   await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page1), parameters);
}
```

Page1ViewModel

```
[QueryProperty("Test", "Test")]

 [ObservableProperty]
 Test _test;

async void GoPage2()   
{
       var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Test", Test } })
       await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page2), parameters);
}
```

Page2ViewModel
I just modify a property of Test object and I would go back to
Page1 I would assume I would need to pass Test object.

```
 [QueryProperty("Test", "Test")]
    
 [ObservableProperty]
 Test _test;  

 async void GoBackToPage1()
{
   Test.TestProperty = "newValue";
   var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Test", Test } })
   await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", parameters);
}
```

When I call GoBackToPage1 on Page2ViewModel the exception thrown.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please format your code so it's readable, not one big block of text.  You don't tell us which specific line causes the exception.  And you should look at the `InnerException` property to get details of the root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test on my side, but I could not reproduce this problem.

Please refer to the following code(Suppose the type of my item is `Animal`):

```
public class MainPageViewModel:IQueryAttributable 
{
    public Animal item { get; private set; }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        item = query["Test"] as Animal;
       

    }
}
```

If I passed back data from the detail page with the following code, all works properly.

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel : IQueryAttributable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Animal Monkey { get; private set; }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        Monkey = query["Monkey"] as Animal;
        OnPropertyChanged("Monkey");
    }
    public ItemDetailViewModel () {
        BackCommand = new Command(doSomething);
       
    }

    private async void doSomething(object obj)
    {
        Animal monkey = new Animal();
        monkey.Name = "back test";

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Test", monkey } };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", parameters);
    }

    public ICommand BackCommand { get; private set; }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```