# How to update parent items when delete item on the details page?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I have a CollectionView with items when I tap on one, should be redirected to details page with a delete or update button. When I do the operation how should I refresh the parent collectionview?

ViewModel of the CollectionviewPage:

```
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItems { get; set; }
        
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        TestItems = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>
        {
            new TestItem { Id = 1, Title = "Test Item 1" },
            new TestItem { Id = 2, Title = "Test Item 2" },
            new TestItem { Id = 3, Title = "Test Item 3" }
        };

        ItemSelectedCommand = new Command(OnItemSelected);
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    private void OnItemSelected(TestItem selectedItem)
    {
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(selectedItem));
    }
}
```

ViewModel of the DetailsPage:

```
public class DetailsPageModel : BaseViewModel
{
    TestItem _item;
    
    public TestViewModel(TestItem item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    private async void Delete()
    {
        // Mock Delete from db
       await _repository.Delete(_item);
       await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

So in this case I remove the item from database, but how should I notify from details page the parent that it should update? Shall I pass the whole list to the details page and remove from there, does not seem effective?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#pass-data

Comment: What would you try to point on with that doc? Is my way of navigation is the reason?

Comment: I linked to the "Pass Data" section - showing how to pass parameters when navigating.  This also works when navigating backwards in the stack

Comment: So with that way of passing object I can update and the collectionView object also will be updated. What If I would like to delete on the detailsPage? Should I set the passed object null or how do I delete from the parent list?

Comment: Pass something like "Op=Delete&ID=1234".  There are a thousand ways you could do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved with the following:

Introduced a INavigationService with:

```
public T GetPageViewModel<T>() where T : new()
{
    var pageDetails = Shell.Current.CurrentItem.CurrentItem.Stack.Where(page => page != null && page.BindingContext.GetType() == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (pageDetails != null)
    {
        return (T)pageDetails.BindingContext;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Added a Refresh method to the TestViewModel and on the DetailsPageModel I call the refresh method of the TestViewModel  after delete/update.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you a quick solution for your implementation but not the best one, pass an action in your constructor and invoke when you want to update your list.

```
[RelayCommand]
private void OnItemSelected(TestItem selectedItem)
{
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(selectedItem, RemoveItem));
}

private void RemoveItem(TestItem selectedItem)
{
    TestItems.Remove(selectedItem)
}
```

Detail Page:

```
public class DetailsPageModel : BaseViewModel
{
    TestItem _item;
    private Action<TestItem> _removeItemAction;
    
    public TestViewModel(TestItem item, Action<TestItem> removeItemAction)
    {
        _item = item;
        _removeItemAction = removeItemAction;
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    private async void Delete()
    {
        // Mock Delete from db
       await _repository.Delete(_item);
       _removeItemAction.Invoke(_item);
       await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

I recommend you to start passing data with Shell Navigation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#pass-data

Answer (score 0):

You can pass back data from the detail page with [Pass multiple use object-based navigation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#pass-multiple-use-object-based-navigation-data).

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel : IQueryAttributable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Animal Monkey { get; private set; }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        Monkey = query["Monkey"] as Animal;
        OnPropertyChanged("Monkey");
    }
    public ItemDetailViewModel () {
        BackCommand = new Command(doSomething);
       
    }

    private async void doSomething(object obj)
    {
        Animal monkey = new Animal();
        monkey.Name = "back test";

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Test", monkey } };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", parameters);
    }

    public ICommand BackCommand { get; private set; }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Refer:  [navigate and pass parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78002437/system-reflection-targetinvocationexception-when-navigate-and-pass-parameter)